# Body weight exercises for arm wrestling

Tags: strength, arms, bodyweight-exercises

I am wondering what body weight exercises might be best to improve arm wrestling skills. Of course not on a professional level, in this case I'd buy equipment, just for the pub level difficulty.

My current goal would be to just improve strength to win (of course). My far goal would be to actually go in the 'negative' region, let the opponent think that he is winning, and push him back then.

So, which body weight exercises will help me reaching this goal. Exercises that make use of a 1.5 Liter water bottle might be acceptable for me, too.

Comment: [This question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/1249/3941) is related but not a duplicate as it doesn't aim for body weight exercises.

Comment: I'm too lazy to actually list exercises, but click [here](http://www.exrx.net/Articulations/Shoulder.html). The motion you need is Medial Rotation. Look for exercises that work those muscles, and it'll improve your arm wrestling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For arm wrestling your going to want to work out the shoulder and arm muscles.

[Chair dips](http://sportsmedicine.about.com/od/strengthtraining/qt/Chair-Dips.htm)(Triceps)

[Narrow grip push ups](http://www.gain-weight-muscle-fast.com/close-grip-push-ups.html)(Triceps)

[Chin ups and Inverted Chin ups](http://www.unique-bodyweight-exercises.com/bicep-exercises.html) (Biceps)

[Push ups](http://www.livestrong.com/article/111835-bodyweight-shoulder-exercises/) (Shoulders)

[Superman](http://www.livestrong.com/article/111835-bodyweight-shoulder-exercises/) (Shoulders)

General overall upper body strength will help. These exercises work more than one muscle which should only help and not harm your case. If it was me I would start a strength program that works the whole body. Buts thats just my opinion.

Unfortunately the exercises I mentioned do not incorporate your 1.5 litre water bottle. (Perhaps fill it with water and drink from it during your rest periods) ;)

Comment: I'd say specifically one handed chin ups would be pretty pertinent to arm wrestling.

Comment: Nothing for forearms?

Answer (score 1):

Muscle Ups. 
If you can do them you'll have the explosive upper body strength and transition power that'll help you get that wrist break leverage that leads to winning in arm wrestling.